# woocommerce subscription recurring not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment

I used woocommerce product to subscribe with free trial period through stripe payment gateway in my site.I have used woocommerce,woocommerce subscription,woocommerce stripe gateway plugins for this process.I checked this in localhost with test stripe account.

First payment for subscription is working fine,but recurring payment is not working with stripe even also i run schedule action option in wordpress and not able to see the error log.I created subscription plan in stripe in name of Basic. can anyone provide solution for this issue?